# Remove last character every line using regex

Tags: regex

I have the [following regex](https://regex101.com/r/nK6pG7/3):

```
\|.*
```

With this, regex, I'm trying to remove last characters in

```
34102103|BLK|2|12|23|9|0|46
34102103|DNY|50|50|50|50
35102100|BLK|3|1|12
35102100|CEM|0|0|0|10|5|0|15
```

I want my output like this:

```
34102103|BLK|2|12|23|9|0
34102103|DNY|50|50|50
35102100|BLK|3|1
35102100|CEM|0|0|0|10|5|0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a negated character class instead of a greedy dot matching.

```
\|[^|]*$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bF2aB3/1)